# How to determine a proportionately decreasing weight given a list of N elements?

Tags: python, statistics

I have a list composed of N elements. For context, I am making a time series forecast, and - once the forecasts have been made - would like to weight the forecasts made at the beginning as more important than the later forecasts. This is useful because when I calculate performance error scores ([MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error)), this score will be representative of **both** the forecasts per item, as well as based on how I want to identify good vs. bad models.

**How should I update my existing function in order to take any list of elements (N) in order to generate these steadily decreasing weights?**

Here is the function that I have come up with on my own. It works for examples like `compute_equal_perc(5)`, but not for other combinations...

```
def compute_equal_perc(rng):
    perc_allocation = []
    equal_perc = 1 / rng
    half_rng = rng / 2
    step_val = equal_perc / (rng - 1)
    print(step_val)

    for x in [v for v in range(0, rng)]:
        if x == int(half_rng):
            perc_allocation.append(equal_perc)
        elif x < int(half_rng):
            diff_plus = ((abs(int(half_rng) - x) * step_val)) + equal_perc
            perc_allocation.append(round(float(diff_plus), 3))
        elif x >= int(half_rng):
            diff_minus = equal_perc - ((abs(int(half_rng) - x) * step_val))
            perc_allocation.append(round(float(diff_minus), 3))
    return perc_allocation
```

For `compute_equal_perc(5)`, the output that I get is:

```
[0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1]
```

The `sum` of this sequence should always equal 1, and the increments between values should always be equal.

Comment: Just a comment, are you checking on ACF and PACF to find a better measurement for the weights ?

Comment: Hi @CeliusStingher, will using this provide a set of weights that sum to 100%? I am not using this today. The reason for this is primarily because it is easy to understand.

Comment: You need to adjust them to sum 100%, but this is a must if you are working with time-series. And it's fully statistics-related, that's why I'm not answering your question as it is not programming.

Comment: Got it - should I then delete this question and move it to Cross-Validated?

Comment: No, this `weights` can be adjusted by more techniques than I can even think of (stochastic gradient descent to mention one) so I believe this should be the right place, however from a performance point of view, I don't think there would be any harm done if you ask in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or another exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved through the application of basic algebra.  An arithmetic sequence is defined as

```
A[i] = a + b*i, for i = 0, 1, 2, 3, ... where a is the initial term
```

The sum of a sequence of elements 0 through n is

```
S = (A[0] + A[n]) * (n+1) / 2
```

in words, sum of the first and list terms, times half the number of terms.

Since you know `S` and `n`, you need only decide one more "spread" factor to generate your sequence.  The mean element must be `1/n` -- this is where your algorithm is wrong, as it fumbles this computation for even values of `n`.

---

Your code fails in this coupling of statements:

```
half_rng = rng / 2
step_val = equal_perc / (rng - 1)
# comparing x to int(half_rng)
```

If `rng` is even, you assign the mean value to position `rng/2`, giving you something such as the list for 4 elements:

```
[0.417, 0.333, 0.25, 0.167]
```

This means that you have two elements larger than the desired mean, and only one smaller, forcing the sum over 1.0.  Instead, when you have an even quantity of elements, you have to make the mean a "phantom" middle element, and take half-steps around it.  Let's look at this with fractions: you already have

```
[5/12, 4/12, 3/12, 2/12]
```

Your difference is 1/12 ... `1 / (n * (n-1))` ... and you need to shift these values lower by half a step.  Instead, the solution with the spread you've chosen (1/12) would be starting a half-step to the side: subtract 1/24 from each element.

```
[9/24, 7/24, 5/24, 3/24]
```

You could also change your step with a simple linear factor.  Decide on the ratio you want for your elements in simple integers, such as `5:4:3:2`, and then generate your weights from the obvious sum of 5+4+3+2:

```
[5/14, 4/14, 3/14, 2/14]
```

Note that this works with any arithmetic sequence of integers, another way of choosing your "spread".  If you use `4:3:2:1` you get

```
[4/10, 3/10, 2/10, 1/10]
```

or you can cluster them more closely with, say, `13:12:11:10`

```
[13/46, 12/46, 11/46, 10/46]
```

So ... pick the spread you want and simplify your code to take advantage of that.